# Getting GraphViz to eliminate identical duplicate edges

Tags: graphviz

I have the following .dot language file for GraphViz:

```
digraph {
    graph [ dpi = 300 ];
    Hello -> World
    Hello -> World
    Hello -> World
}
```

Which renders as:

[image]

The code is produced programmatically, hence the duplication.

But I don't want the duplicate links i.e. I want it to render as:

[image]

Yes, I could add logic to the program that produces the dot file, but if there is a GraphViz parameter to do this it’d be very useful.

Thanks.

Edit: Raising the dead here, but the question of which this is marked as a duplicate has multiple connections between 2 nodes but each with different labels, so not exactly the same, although the suggestion to use the ‘strict’ keyword does work.

Edit: Again voting to reopen, as the question that someone thinks this is a duplicate of is, in fact, a different question. This is about duplicate edges and the other questions isn't. The fact that the same answer works is irrelevant, just as "What is 2+2?" and "what is 3+1?" are different questions, despite having the same answer.

Comment: 'Original' question edited because the title was incorrect, leading to the confusion perhaps that this is a duplicate. The edges in the other question are NOT the same but have different labels.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

‘strict’ was the answer :

```
strict digraph {
    graph [ dpi = 300 ];
    Hello -> World
    Hello -> World
    Hello -> World
}
```

Edit:

From https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html :

> *A graph may also be described as strict. This forbids the creation of
> multi-edges, i.e., there can be at most one edge with a given tail
> node and head node in the directed case. For undirected graphs, there
> can be at most one edge connected to the same two nodes. Subsequent
> edge statements using the same two nodes will identify the edge with
> the previously defined one and apply any attributes given in the edge
> statement.*